# Ionic / Angular DatePicker programmatically change value

Tags: javascript, angularjs, datepicker, ionic-framework

I am now using the plain HTML5-style datepicker by adding `type="date"` to the input-element. This looks good and works with picking dates and using them. But I want to be able to set the value of the datepicker programmatically, to enforce ranges the user is able to choose from.

The element now looks like this:

```
<input type="date" 
  placeholder="Choose startdate" 
  ng-model="rangeStart"
  ng-change="changeRangeStart(rangeStart)"
>
```

There is also a button to reset the date to today, for example. This is how I try to do that:

```
// today is a Date-object
$scope.rangeStart = today;
```

EDIT// ^ changed rangeEnd to rangeStart (typo)

Anyone who can help me with this? Now the user can set the date, but I want to be able to change the date *for* the user.

Comment: Just update the `rangeStart` object in your controller, the DOM will change accordingly

Comment: I made a type in the question, I edited it. So what you say is what I am already doing. Any other suggestions?

Comment: I think you need to get the month, date and year out from the date object and then concatenate them as one string and pass is as $scope.rangeStart